# AJAX Collapsible Panel HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax

I am trying to add an AJAX Collapsible Panel to my HTML page. I know you can do a AJAX Collapsible Panel using asp.net fairly easily. However, I need to add one to an already existing HTML page. Any ideas how to do this using HTML, Javascript and AJAX? Thanks

Comment: so you want to add options to the dropdown by ajax ? did i understood well ?

Comment: I want to make something similar to the two lower list on this page the "CascadingDropDown Description" and "CascadingDropDown Properties" I guess it is a Collapsible Panel not drop down list:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: and where are you going to get the corresponding lists for each selection ? you will use some server side script anyway

Comment: no, there are only a few I need to add so I will hard code them or store in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add an onchange event to the first select
2. In the handler place an Ajax call and populate the second select with the results
3. The Ajax call should accept a single parameter (query string) and return key/value collection as Json

You might actually find this way is easier (with Jquery) than using the ASP.net Ajax stuff.